# Evaluating a transfer function from .Net

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use Matlab to evaluate a continuous transfer function using data I am generating in a .net application.
I have created a M file with the following code:

```
function out = transfer(in)
     s = tf('s')
     H = s^2/(s^2+5*s+6.25)
end
```

What should the input parameter be, and how to use it with the transfer function H?

Once I know that, I'm guessing I can use the various ways of hitting a matlab function from .net; which shouldn't be too bad once I have the function correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define `H` as transfer function as well:

```
H = tf( [ 1 0 0 ] , [ 1 5 6.25] );
```

you need to define `s = tf('s')` just if you want to use it for further calculations.

Then you can calculate the system response of your data `t` (time) and `u` (values)

```
t = 0:0.01:4;
u = sin(10*t);
response = lsim(H,u,t)
```

If your data doesn't have a fixed time step you could a create a [timeseries object](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/timeseriesclass.html) first. And use `sim` instead of `lsim`.

Comment: I'm getting inputs every 0.1 seconds as a decimal number (acceleration). I can put them into any format I wish really.  Is lsim just for testing it, or for real use?

Comment: of course it's for real use. I added `response` - this vector contains the output/response data for every time step. So create a time-vector like above, with your step-size, take care that all vectors have the same length (time and input data) and it will work.

Comment: I've done some further research and it seems lsim is used to evaluate a fixed time period. How do I use tf with over a continuous time period. Ie. every 0.1 seconds I receive a new data point, how do I evaluate the function up to the current time?

Comment: see answer. Or provide some data, then I could try it also.

Comment: So it looks like I can do addsample each time step, and sim against a simulink model? But when I try I get "TIMESPAN" parameter must be a real scalar or vector. The data is literally a double value every 0.1 seconds.

Comment: I really don't get whats wrong with the solution I already posted. Have you tried it? What result do you expect, if not that?